# Eclipse/LibgGdx - How to add a Gradle Dependency

Tags: java, ios, eclipse, libgdx

I am creating a LibGdx application for which I would like to add advertisements using Mopub. I am currently attempting to get it working on iOS and I have tried importing the Mopub Robovm bindings with the source project found [here](https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings) and the compiled [jar](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/robovm-ios-bindings/) (that index is not a repo, correct?) as a Gradle dependency, however in both cases I have received this error when deploying:

```
7/29/14 8:32:24 PM: [ERROR] Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
7/29/14 8:32:24 PM: [ERROR]   "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSManagedObject", referenced from:
7/29/14 8:32:24 PM: [ERROR]       _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CBStory in libmopub.a(CBStory.o)
7/29/14 8:32:24 PM: [ERROR]   "_NSSQLiteStoreType", referenced from:
7/29/14 8:32:24 PM: [ERROR]       -[CBStoryStorageManager persistentStoreCoordinator] in libmopub.a(CBStoryStorageManager.o)
7/29/14 8:32:24 PM: [ERROR]   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSPersistentStoreCoordinator", referenced from:
7/29/14 8:32:24 PM: [ERROR]       objc-class-ref in libmopub.a(CBStoryStorageManager.o)
7/29/14 8:32:25 PM: [ERROR]   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObjectModel", referenced from:
7/29/14 8:32:25 PM: [ERROR]       objc-class-ref in libmopub.a(CBStoryStorageManager.o)
7/29/14 8:32:25 PM: [ERROR]   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObject", referenced from:
7/29/14 8:32:25 PM: [ERROR]       objc-class-ref in libmopub.a(CBStoryStorageManager.o)
7/29/14 8:32:25 PM: [ERROR]       _OBJC_CLASS_$_CBStory in libmopub.a(CBStory.o)
7/29/14 8:32:25 PM: [ERROR]   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAttributeDescription", referenced from:
7/29/14 8:32:25 PM: [ERROR]       objc-class-ref in libmopub.a(CBStoryStorageManager.o)
7/29/14 8:32:25 PM: [ERROR]   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEntityDescription", referenced from:
7/29/14 8:32:25 PM: [ERROR]       objc-class-ref in libmopub.a(CBStoryStorageManager.o)
7/29/14 8:32:25 PM: [ERROR]   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSManagedObjectContext", referenced from:
7/29/14 8:32:25 PM: [ERROR]       objc-class-ref in libmopub.a(CBStoryStorageManager.o)
7/29/14 8:32:25 PM: [ERROR]   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFetchRequest", referenced from:
7/29/14 8:32:25 PM: [ERROR]       objc-class-ref in libmopub.a(CBStoryStorageManager.o)
7/29/14 8:32:26 PM: [ERROR] ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
7/29/14 8:32:26 PM: [ERROR] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
7/29/14 8:32:26 PM: [ERROR] Build failed
```

I think I followed the steps for implementing the source project correctly, but I have no idea if I did the Gradle dependency correctly. What I did for the dependency was create a folder to hold the mopub-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar and then put this call in the dependency section of the base projects build.gradle file under the iOS section:

```
compile files ("libs/mopub-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar")
```

If that is not correct, please inform me on the proper method. Thereafter, Eclipse told me to put that local jar on the build path because it was giving build errors, so I did.

The code is working, or at least compiling, but how do I actually manage to deploy it (or even to correctly add the jar as a Gradle dependency, if I was doing it incorrectly)?

**EDIT**
I used `compile fileTree` and this actually put the jar in the Gradle Dependencies, but I'm still getting the error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the framework CoreData to my robovm.xml file solved the error! Now I just need to figure out how to send the AdManager (interface made by recommendation of LibGdx "Working with platform-specific code" tutorial) to my main game class, because it can only create the ad in the didFinishLaunching method.